# Secret sharing in different groups; Rounding down of elements

Tags: secret-sharing, group-theory

I have the following problem:

A secret $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q$ is secret shared (additive secret sharing) between $n$ parties, now is it possible to compute the secret shares of $y = \lfloor x \rfloor _p $ without reconstructing the secret $x$.

$ y = \lfloor x \cdot \frac{p}{q} \rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}_p  \text{    } p < q $. Essentially I need the shares of rounded down version of $x$, is there a way to do that?

Comment: In the simplest $(n,n)$ additive secret sharing scheme, $n-1$ shares $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ are randomly chosen nonzero elements of the field while the $n$-th share is $x-x_1-x_2-\cdots -x_{n-1}$ where the difference is calculated _in the field_, that is, $x$ _is_ equal to the sum $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$ modulo $p$ already and you _have_ reconstructed $x$. So, more details of what you mean by additive secret sharing would help in getting an answer.

Comment: The setting is that a dealer $D$ generates the shares of $x$ and distributes among $n$ parties, now the parties need to participate in a multiparty computation to compute shares of $y$ from shares of $x$, the dealer is not (should not be) involved in this step

Comment: So the $n$ shareholders can get together and find $x$, then $x \bmod p$, and recompute the values of the shares. Indeed, unless you are insisting that the new shares have values smaller than $p$, $x_i$ can be the same for $i<n$ while $x_n$ gets changed to $y-x_1 -x_2-\cdots -x_{n-1}$.

Comment: I do not want them to compute $x$ which lets everyone know $x$. I was wondering if generating the new shares is possible by performing just local computation on the shares.

Answer (score 3):

Consider an additive secret sharing with two parties (this argument extends to many parties). Let $x = x_0 + x_1 \pmod q$.

Suppose, each party locally rounds its own share ($x_i$, for $i \in \{0,1\}$). The question is what happens to $\lfloor x_0 \rfloor_p + \lfloor x_1 \rfloor_p \pmod p$.

Unpacking the definition of $\lfloor x \rfloor_p = \lfloor x \frac{p}{q} \rfloor$, we can expand the addition (mod $p$) as:
$$
\lfloor x_0 \rfloor_p + \lfloor x_1 \rfloor_p 
= \lfloor x_0\tfrac{p}{q} \rfloor + \lfloor x_1 \tfrac{p}{q} \rfloor 
= \lfloor (x_0 + x_1)\tfrac{p}{q} \rfloor + e = \lfloor (x_0 + x_1) \rfloor_p + e, 
$$
where $e \in \{0,1,2\}$.
Hence, the parties would get shares of $\lfloor y \rfloor_p + e$.
However, note that $e$ is "small" relative to $p$, if $p$ is sufficiently "large".

The above argument can be extended to many parties in the natural way assuming $n$-out-of-$n$ additive secret shares.

This is a problem that appears, for example, in Key Homomorphic PRFs (see Theorem 5.5 in https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/220.pdf).